# Cocos2d: Why double-speed on retina display?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display

In the update method: of a layer, I'm moving a plane like this:

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    ...

    pos.x += vVelocity.x;
    pos.y += vVelocity.y;
    plane.position = pos;
}
```

Testing as a universal app on iPad it works as expected but when I test on the iPhone 4 the plane moves twice as fast! I am using a -hd image for the retina display version.
Am I missing something or must I half the velocity in the above code when the retina display is used?

Comment: Cocos2D v0.99.5 and newer has retina display support. Which version do you use?

Comment: @phix23 I'm using Cocos2D v1.0...

Answer (score 1):

Cocos2d uses points to measure, so treat screen positions as 480x320 even with retina. It sounds like vVelocity is being based off pixels, so it's double what it should be. The bug is where velocity is being calculated. See http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:how_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d for more information.

Comment: `code`CGPoint pos = plane.position;
`code`pos.x += 1;
`code`plane.position = pos;

Comment: I've simplified the animation code as above and still it runs double-speed on retina display.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce this behaviour. You should multiply the velocity (given in points per second) by delta. This behaves as it should (tested in iOS simulator with and without retina display):

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
    // ...
    CGPoint pos = plane.position;
    pos.x += vVelocity.x*delta;
    pos.y += vVelocity.y*delta;
    plane.position = pos;
}
```

Comment: The problem remained even when I multiplied by delta. I realise now that also on the retina display version, the plane object is being shrunk for some reason It's a clue to what's going on but I don't know what. I'm going to resolve this by rebuilding the project. Thanks.

Comment: `if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {`
`// If NOT on the iPad, scale down plane`
`// In your games, use this to load art sized for the device`
`[plane setScaleX:screenSize.width/1024.0f];`
`[plane setScaleY:screenSize.height/768.0f];`
`}`

Comment: The above code was causing my problem. It was temporary code from a book and should have been removed. Thanks all.